# Disposing objects and restoring them

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working on a three.js project that allows the user to switch through scenes that hold different mesh objects. They're all loaded into the project at the same time when the page has loaded, and all of these objects have textures which weigh heavily on the performance.

So to fix this, I want to **temporarily** remove all the objects in all of the scenes that the user has **not** selected. So, with 10 scenes, should the user for example select to see what's in scene 4 (which would be the `currentScene`), then scene 1 through 3 and 5 through 10 should have no objects that put an unnecessary strain on the performance. This should account as well for when the page has loaded. Only when the user selects one of those aforementioned scenes again, then it restores the scenes' objects.

This [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dxc2wjwr/) is an example of my project that encompasses the essential code. I am using the `remove()` and `dispose()` methods to achieve it.

```
//scene that's to be removed and disposed of
var destroyScenes = scenes[1];

//removes and disposes all objects in above scene

for (i = destroyScenes.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            obj = destroyScenes.children[i];
            destroyScenes.remove(obj);
            obj.geometry.dispose();
            obj.material.dispose();
            obj.texture.
    }
```

My concrete question(s) is this:
How do I restore the objects if I remove and dispose of them? Is that a good approach to it, is it even possible, and/or is there a better way of achieving this?

Also, if that is a way to do it, how do I select all of the scenes except for the `currentScene`?

PS: I'm well aware that it'll put a loading time switching between scenes, but I'd still much more prefer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How do I restore the objects if I remove and dispose of them?**
- If you dispose object right, you must load it again, which is ugly

**Is that a good approach to it, is it even possible, and/or is there a better way of achieving this?**
- If you plan to show object again, it is better to set `obj.visible = false`; Loading and disposing again is the worst performance method. Some things (as is fog etc..) cannot be applied correctly after loading object later.

**Also, if that is a way to do it, how do I select all of the scenes except for the currentScene?**
- Not sure about question, make a new question for that. (by controlling mouse move i guess)

**I'm well aware that it'll put a loading time switching between scenes, but I'd still much more prefer that.** 
- It's not a way how it works. Scenes are running at the same time, you can stop animation frame for inactive scenes. But scenes will load on initialisation, not during switching them.

*Ask always only one question pls.*

Comment: So would setting `obj.visible = false` improve performance then? Even more so in combination with `cancelAnimationFrame`? Would you say that that's the best approach to it? Thanks

Comment: If you stom animation of unused scenes and replace hiding, showing objects instead of loading and destroying them, yes it is better and it is a best practise

Comment: Great. I have programmed to set all scenes except the `currentScene` to `visible = false;` Would you know how to help me out with the cancelAnimationFrame? It seems that one's a bit harder to implement. https://jsfiddle.net/rm8tLpy5/1/

Comment: I think I'll just ask that as a new question. Thank you.

Comment: conversely, animate only scene where you have something active (mouse, is switched or etc...) you don't need to cancel animation, only stop, or make a condition in each animate() fnc. animate() {if(scene_active) { // dostuff} else {// scene inactive, animation running}}