# How do I stop animations for multiples scenes except the current one?

Tags: javascript, three.js

My program has multiple scenes. Only 1 scene will be at all times visible of course, so how do I stop the animation for all the other scenes except the current scene to improve performance? There are 10 scenes and each of them has a lot of objects that strain the performance.

I know it can be probably done with `cancelAnimationFrame()`, but how to implement it? Supposedly, this is the best practice as [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41434654/5809130) to go about it in order to improve performance?

The 10 scenes are an array of scenes. The current scene is the user input numerical value passed to the `scenes[]` array.

```
function changeScene() {
    // Set the currentScene to the user selection
        var sceneNumber = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;
        currentScene = scenes[sceneNumber-1];
    // Hide all scenes by default    
        for(var j=0;j<10;j++){
        scenes[j].visible = false;
    }   
}
```

I have already programmed all scenes to be hidden by default except for the `currentScene`. But I have found no help researching how to use the `cancelAnimationFrame()` in my case. Also, a follow-up question: will using `cancelAnimationFrame()` only activate after the page has loaded all the scenes with all the objects? Or would it help that loading time as well?

My [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/youLxxze/) with the above and related code.

Comment: According to your jsfiddle example, you already work with one and only scene which you set as current. There is no animation or rendering for the other scenes.

Comment: Okay, I'm confused. Then how is it that when there are a lot of objects inside a lot of scenes, and the `currentScene` has relatively few objects in my actual program, that it takes a while to load the page if all the other scenes are set to `visible = false` AND the animations to those scenes are stopped? What else could be the reason and/or fix to the loading time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation is the change of numeric parameters over time. In your example that means changing the `spinningRig` rotation angle inside your `animate()` method. As long as you change the rotation for the current scene only -- which you actually do -- the other scenes are not being animated.

If you're perhaps addressing rendering instead of animation there is again no need to worry because Three.JS renders only the one scene you specify in `renderer.render()`.

Or are you addressing anything other? Animation clearly isn't a problem here.

Comment: In my real program the objects I'm adding to the scenes are from an array and each object are given textures. If I push a real big number of objects, like 1000 to the scenes then the loading time of the page is drastically longer than if it were 10 objects. How can that be though, when the objects in all scenes are set to invisible by default, except for the `currentScene`. I was also under the wrong impression that the animations were still running for those scenes. But if it's not visibility and animations, what else could be the problem?

Comment: So loading is the problem. The loader in Three.js does not take into account which scenes are visible and which not. There are plenty good reasons for that (preloading, model shared across scenes, etc.) I'm afraid you will have to manage this yourself, e.g. first load the models from the visible scene and only then start loading the other models..